# Twilio SMS to Softphone Bria/SessionTalk

Tags: sms, twilio

How can Twilio SMS messaging be integrated with SIP soft phones such as Bria and SessionTalk. Both those examples support sms messaging via SIP Simple but there is a dirth of documentation on how to set this up.

For the purpose of this question assume that a Twilio messaging service is already set up and tested to work. There is also an external server available if additional coding is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIP SIMPLE is not a protocol Twilio supports, so direct integration is not possible.